# (react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css) error in react js

Tags: reactjs, toast, react-toastify

I am trying to add toast message in react js I install package using this (npm add react-toastify) but when I use this (import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';) this is giving error see error in images

[image: using]

[image: error]

Comment: What do you mean by `npm add`.  It should be `npm install` or `yarn add` ?. Anyway, I just created a simple react application and added `toastify` library. It works perfectly. Can you check if you have installed that library correctly?

Comment: @SankaSanjeewa  please check this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-toast-notification/

Comment: You can follow their official documentation instead of this.

Comment: @SankaSanjeewa, please give official documentation link or example

Comment: Docs:- https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction

Comment: @SankaSanjeewa, but its css gives error please see this image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wqk4-YSSaUzoSb2loaTRu6YdRPIQOMzr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255677/discussion-between-sanka-sanjeewa-and-m-junaid).